# Getting the output of a cat command into an array

Tags: arrays, bash

How can I get just the filenames into an array using the cat command?

How I've been trying:

```
array=()
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0'; do
  array+=("$REPLY")
done < <(cat /proc/swaps | grep "swap")
```

This either grabs all the information from the output into an array, or just doesn't work. How can I successfully get my expected output of `[/swapfile, /dev/hda1, /some/other/swap]` into an array form using the cat command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
readarray array < <(awk '/swap/{print $1}' /proc/swaps)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash introduced `readarray` in version 4 which can take the place of the while read loop. `readarray` is the solution you want.

here is the syntax

```
readarray variable < inputfile
echo "${variable[0]}" ' to print the first element in array
```